# Ext JS 4 filter feature without unnecessary sorting and menu

Tags: extjs

How can I create a filter in Ext JS 4 without sorting feature and menu, need just "search" text field. For example with this code:

```
        var gridGroups = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        columns: [
            {dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1},
        ],
        features: [{
            ftype: 'filters',
            encode: true,
            local: true,
            filters: [{
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }]
        }],
        ....
```

I got this result with unnecessary menu and sorting, but I need only search field[image]
So, the search field must be here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, managing the menu directly is not possible by in a scratch (without side effects). Menu control of visible column state will be hidden only if you set the `hideable: false` for all columns. Sorting menuitem hide only for `sortable: false` column's.

You can use next override for hide menuitems:

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.header.ContainerOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.header.Container',
    getMenuItems: function () {
        var me = this,
            grid = this.grid,
            hideSortInHeaderMenu = grid.hideSortInHeaderMenu,
            hideColumnSettingsInHeaderMenu = grid.hideColumnSettingsInHeaderMenu,
            menuItems = [],
            hideableColumns = me.enableColumnHide ? me.getColumnMenu(me) : null;

        if (me.sortable && !hideSortInHeaderMenu) {
            menuItems = [{
                itemId: 'ascItem',
                text: me.sortAscText,
                iconCls: me.menuSortAscCls,
                handler: me.onSortAscClick,
                scope: me
            }, {
                itemId: 'descItem',
                text: me.sortDescText,
                iconCls: me.menuSortDescCls,
                handler: me.onSortDescClick,
                scope: me
            }];
        }
        if (hideableColumns && hideableColumns.length && !hideColumnSettingsInHeaderMenu) {
            if (me.sortable) {
                menuItems.push({
                    itemId: 'columnItemSeparator',
                    xtype: 'menuseparator'
                });
            }
            menuItems.push({
                itemId: 'columnItem',
                text: me.columnsText,
                iconCls: me.menuColsIcon,
                menu: hideableColumns,
                hideOnClick: false
            });
        }
        return menuItems;
    }
})
```

[Work example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36ga)